# Consulta de dos Modelos en Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

tengo estos dos modelos:

```
class Pacientes(models.Model):
nombres = models.CharField(max_length=50)
apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=50)
numero_identificacion = models.CharField(max_length=10)
fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(blank=False,)
celular = models.CharField(max_length=10)
email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
direccion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
genero = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PACIENTE_SEXO)



class Citas(models.Model):
estado = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ESTADOS_CITA, 
default=ESTADO_INGRESADO)
laboratorio = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=LABORATORIO_TODOS, 
null=True)
idexamen = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=EXAMENES_TODOS)
idpaciente = models.ForeignKey(Pacientes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
doctor = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=DOCTORES_TODOS)
```

Lo que deseo hacer es una consulta que en SQL seria:

```
select c.estado, c.laboratorio, c.idexamen, p.nombres, p.apellidos, c.doctor
from pacientes p, citas c
where c.idpaciente = p.id
```

Alguien me puede dar una ayuda.Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a Django esto no es nada complicado, voy a suponer que el id=1 del paciente existe:

```
# Observación: para el nombre de los modelos se usan palabras en singular, los fields con relaciones se suele poner con el nombre del modelo por ejemplo: en vez de idpaciente pon simplemente paciente
try:
   paciente = Pacientes.objects.get(id=1)
   citas = Citas.objects.filter(idpaciente=paciente)
   for c in citas:
       print("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6}".format(c.estado, c.laboratorio, c.idexamen, c.idpaciente.nombres, c.idpaciente.apellidos, c.idpaciente.doctor))
```

el filtro de las citas de un paciente dado un id se puede hacer de dos formas la q te he mostrado lineas anteriores y la q te muestro ahora:

```
citas = Citas.objects.filter(idpaciente__id=1)
```

como idpaciente es un FK de paciente con el doble guion bajo podemos hacer referencia a cualquiera de sus atributos desde Citas

Answer (score 0):

Prueba el método raw para ejecutar consultas SQL personalizadas en Django

```
resultado = Paciente.objects.raw('select c.estado, c.laboratorio, c.idexamen, 
p.nombres, p.apellidos, c.doctor
from pacientes p, citas c
where c.idpaciente = p.id')
```